# Como passar valor para label em modal

Tags: jquery, modal

Preencho os inputs da minha modal, da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDescricao" name="txtDescricao" minlenght="4" required>
```

Script:

```
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="txtDescricao"]').val(descricao)
```

E quando tenho um label, do tipo:

```
<label for="teste"></label>
```

Como passo o valor da variável **descricao** para ele?

Comment: Precisa usar esse modal.find não no evento do show da modal só faz $("#txtDescricao").val('VALOR_AQUI'); da uma olhada -> http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/7ax1w7td/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você passar o delimitador no caso o `id` do seu input:

```
var novoLabel = $('#textoDescricao').val();
$("#teste").text(novoLabel);
```

Assim você não utilizaria este "modal.find", basta procurar o delimitador do elemento e passá-lo via jQuery.

No seu caso, por ser um `label` deve-se utilizar o `.text()` pois o mesmo pega o texto do seu label e o modifica pelo novo valor, se fosse um `input` você deveria utilizar o `.val()`

Segue um jsFiddle com o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wakeupmh/cmL9bdfa/

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
$('.modal-body label').text(descricao)
```